# Limit of an integral - Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Assume $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and integrable in $(0,1)$. Find $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^k f(x) dx $

Note that here, integrablity of $f$ in $(0,1)$ means $\int_0^1 f(x) < \infty$, not the Lebesgue integrability which is $\int_0^1 |f(x)| < \infty$

I can solve the problem when $f$ is non-negative or $f \subset \mathbb{L_1}(0,1)$, but I don't know how to deal with it otherwise

Comment: But $ f $ being integrable on $(0,1)$ is the same as saying $f\in L^1(0,1).$

Comment: @zhw. why ? You mean $\int_0^1 f(x) dx <\infty$ yields $\int_0^1 |f(x)| dx <\infty$ ? It is not necessarily true.

Comment: Review the definition of "integrable" in measure theory.

Comment: @zhw You are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|x^k f(x)|\leq |f(x)|\in L^1(0,1),$$

then use dominated convergence theorem.